# Storing Passwords in HTML5 LocalStorage

Tags: security, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I need to store passwords in the HTML5 LocalStorage (No, I can't use hashes and I can't ask the user to type his password).

What is the most secure way to do this? I understand that this can never be *really* safe, but I'm just looking to secure this **as much as possible**.

Can you do encryption in JavaScript? If yes, what is the best encryption algorithm for this task?

Thank you.

Comment: Talking about JS client-side encryption: http://shop-js.sourceforge.net/crypto2.htm ; http://www.jcryption.org/ ; http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html

Comment: The AES library looks nice. What should I use as a salt? Some constant string or what?

Comment: A different random string, +6 characters would be good, for each login:password pair IMO Generally speaking you shouldn't use the same salt for two logins besause it's then easy to spot password reuse (ex: "12345") just by findind duplicate hashes.

Comment: Can you genarate encription server side and store it client side ?

Comment: No, I don't have server side, it's a packaged Chrome app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure library has a set of encoding algorithms in Javascript, maybe one of those can help:
[http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fclosure%2Fgoog%2Fcrypt](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/#svn/trunk/closure/goog/crypt)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my (ancient) N97 web-runtime application.
I used [JavaScrypt](http://www.fourmilab.ch/javascrypt/) which worked fine for me.